# How do I generate a calculated output based on input in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that takes in an integer value from a user and then prints the calculated solution. More specifically take the amount of hours worked in a week multiplied by the regpay and if the hours is over 35, regpay gets multiplied by 1 and a half. The calculations are right, I just can't make the hours into an input form so that I can multiply it.

I'm completely new to Java and have been looking everywhere for a solution. Help is GREATLY appreciated.

Here is the code I worked on so far: 
    package chapter1_prog4;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Brian
*/
public class Chapter1_Prog4 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String hours;
    System.out.print("Enter amount of hours worked for the week:");
    hours = userInput.next();

    double regpay, earned, overh;

    regpay = 15;
    earned = 0;
    overh = 0;

    if (hours<=35)
        earned = (hours*regpay);
    else
        overh = ((hours-35)*(regpay*1.5));
        earned = (35*regpay)+overh;

    System.out.println( "Amount earned before taxes: $" + earned);

 }
 }
```

Comment: You could _not_ have made that title more generic. Please consider editing your question to include a more meaningful title (the edit button is right above this comment ;) )

Comment: You might be missing brackets in your `if-else`.

Comment: `hours` is a `String`

Comment: As for your question, use nextInt and store hours as an integer, or use `Integer.parseInt` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: did you mean to say, `"store hours as an int"`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I do believe that `int` indeed is how you'd typically store an integer in Java  (Fun fact - I keep reading your username with hungarian accent) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to multiply a `String` by a `double`, which does not work. Try to input one of the numeric types for `hours`

Change the following part

```
String hours;
System.out.print("Enter amount of hours worked for the week:");
hours = userInput.next();
```

To

```
double hours;
System.out.println("Enter amount of hours worked for the week: "); 
hours = userInput.nextDouble();
```

There is also a mistake in the if-statement

Change

```
if (hours<=35)
    earned = (hours*regpay);
else
    overh = ((hours-35)*(regpay*1.5));
    earned = (35*regpay)+overh;
```

To

```
if (hours<=35) {
    earned = (hours*regpay);
} else {
    overh = ((hours-35)*(regpay*1.5));
    earned = (35*regpay)+overh;
}
```

The thing is, if you do not wrap what follows `if` and `else` in those curly braces, only the first statement after each of them will be seen. In the above uncorrected example, `earned = (35*regpay)+overh;` will always be calculated, because it is not in the scope of the `else` statement

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem of inputting the hours but now when a value less than 35 is placed the calculation is wrong.

Comment: Because your if-else statement needs to be wrapped in curly braces, I've updated the answer

Comment: THANK YOU!! I've been searching online for hours now. I wish I could do more to repay you!

Answer (score 0):

String can't be used the same as Integers, in Java following line **doesn't compile** :

```
if ("string" <= 100)
```

Many solutions are applicable, here's one

After this line :

```
hours = userInput.next();
```

Add this line :

```
Integer hoursInteger = Integer.valueOf(hours);
```

and refactor all your references from hours to `hoursInteger`.

Comment: Thank you! Again, this solves the problem but now the calculations is wrong when a value less than 35 is placed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the input from user is a String, which can be converted to a float or int. Here is an example:

```
String hours = "3.2";
int integer = Integer.parseInt(hours);
float floatingPointNumber = Float.parseFloat(hours);
```

However, to be on the safe side, if you do this, you should do a try-catch so that if user inputs something other than a number, your program does not crash. Here is an example:

```
String test = "r";
try{
int integer = Integer.parseInt(test);
}catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```